# Changing/adding spatial boundaries/polygon shapefile R

Tags: r, maps, shapefile, r-maptools, rgdal

I'm dealing with an Afghanistan shapefile which contains all of the provinces.  I ultimately want to plot some data by regional command, which each contain several provinces (this is what I'm talking about: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Afghanistan_ISAF_Sept2008.jpg).  I'm not hugely familiar with handling shapefiles in R, but I haven't found much in the way of tutorials on this issue.  Is it possible to re-draw the polygons or overlay the RC boundaries and plot a choropleth that way? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a lookup-table that tells you which province feature is in which regional command? Have you tried the "gUnion" etc functions in the `rgeos` package? Can you share your shapefile? Have you even managed to read it in yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

**Code:**

```
library(rgdal)     # for readOGR(...)
library(ggplot2)   # for fortify(...) and rendering the map
setwd("<directory with all your files>")

regional.commands <- read.csv("regional.commands.csv")

map  <- readOGR(dsn=".", layer="afghanistan_province_boundaries_-_34_provinces")
data <- data.frame(id=rownames(map@data),Province=map@data$Prov34Na)
data <- merge(data,regional.commands,by="Province")
map.df <- fortify(map)
map.df <- merge(map.df,data,by="id", all.x=T)
map.df <- map.df[order(map.df$order),]

ggplot(map.df, aes(x=long,y=lat, group=group))+ 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=RC))+
  geom_path(colour="grey70")+
  coord_fixed()
```

In this example, `regional.commands.csv` was assembled (manually!!!!) from data on the [ISAF website](http://www.isaf.nato.int/news/2.html). This file has just two columns: `Province` and `RC` (regional command). Presumably, you have something like this already, but did not feel the need to share it.  The Afghanistan shapefile was obtained [here](http://geocommons.com/overlays/63469.zip).

**Explanation**

The shapefile is read into R using `readOGR(...)`, creating a "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame" object (`map`). This object has two main sections, a polygons section, which contains the coordinates of the polygon boundaries, and a data section, which contains information about each polygon (such as the province name). The latter can be referenced using `map@data`.

Each polgyon has a unique id. These are stored in the row names of `map@data`. So first we create a data frame `data` with column `id` from the row names of `map@data`, and a column `Province` from the relevant column of `map@data` (column `Prov34Na`).

```
data <- data.frame(id=rownames(map@data),Province=map@data$Prov34Na)
```

If you have a different Afghanistan shapefile, the appropriate column in `map@data` might be different.

Now we merge this with the `regional.commands` data frame based on the common `Province` column.

```
data <- merge(data,regional.commands,by="Province")
```

`data` now has 3 columns: `Province`, `id`, and `RC` (Regional Command). One thing to watch out for is that, evidently, ISAF feels it knows best how to spell the names of Afghanistan's provinces. Some of these do *not* correspond to the spelling in the map attributes table. So you may need to fix that, again, manually...

Now we use `fortify(...)` to create, from `map`, a dataframe suitable for plotting (`map.df`). This data frame has an `id` column, so we merge that with `data` based on `id`.

```
map.df <- merge(map.df,data,by="id", all.x=T)
```

Finally, all this merging messed up the order of the rows, so we re-order using the order column in `map.df`.

```
map.df <- map.df[order(map.df$order),]
```

The rest is just generating the layers and rendering the plot.